# How do I best connect my LCD panel?

Tags: lcd, lvds

I have started an electronics project as a hobby that requires an [TFT-LCD panel](https://www.panelook.com/M170ETN01.1_AUO_17.0_LCM_overview_18909.html) to be directly controlled by a Raspberry Pi / Orange Pi.

More information:

- I would prefer not having a control board, but a direct connection
- It is only the panel itself, not the backlight or any buttons

Is this possible? If so how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reusing laptop monitors](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/30094/64158)

Answer (score 1):

> I would prefer not having a control board, but a direct connection

Not possible.

The panel you linked is a 1280x1024 17" panel and requires 2-ch LVDS which is not directly available on an RPi. Possible with some extension/interface/adapter boards which are already available.